# Jquery A-Z Filter with numbers

Tags: jquery

Having an issue of an A-Z filter skipping any row with a linked number.

When choosing "A" in the alpha list any listing with a phone number included will not display.

```
var alphas = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
var tmp = '';
        for (var x = 0; x < 26; x++) tmp += '<a href="#">' + alphas[x].toUpperCase() + '</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        $('#table_filter').append(tmp);

        $('#table_filter a').click(function () {

           if ($(this).attr('id') == 'show_all') {
              $('#searchNames tbody tr').css('display', 'table-row');
              $('#message').html('displaying all rows');
              return false;
           }

           var alpha = $(this).html();
           $('#searchNames tbody tr').hide().filter(function () {
              var td = $('td:first', $(this));
              return td.length && td.html() && new RegExp('^' + alpha + '.*$', 'i').test(td.html().toLowerCase());
           }).css('display', 'table-row');
           $('#message').html('displaying rows with "' + alpha + '"');
           return false;
        })
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/axedz9rt/2/

Answer (score 0):

The lists including phone number are covered with `a` tag. So, the value of `td` would be like `<a href="#">Ants</a>` and it's not okay for `'^' + alpha` test.